# Why multiplication returns NA in R

Tags: r

I have a vector F2 in R:

> ```
> F2
>        [,1]
>  [1,] 0.125
>  [2,] 0.875
> ```

And when I prompt F2[1], I get 0.125. when I prompt F2[2], I get 0.875

But when I prompt F2[1]*F[2], I get NA.

I am wondering *why* that is the case, and *what* the correct syntax would be.

Comment: Please make your answer reproducible, particularly provide us with your data. The data I created in my answer (which mimics your data, at least how you describe it above) does not show this problem. See e.g. `dput`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem:

```
m = matrix(runif(2), 2, 1)
m
          [,1]
[1,] 0.4633784
[2,] 0.6180268
> m[1]
[1] 0.4633784
> m[2]
[1] 0.6180268
> m[1]*m[2]
[1] 0.2863803
```

So you'll have to be a bit more specific.

Comment: Please paste this into your question.

Comment: ...and this example data does not match that in your question.

Comment: Paul, that was mysterious, it works now, although I never figured out what I did differently!? Sorry and thanks...

Comment: The problem is solved, that is most important :)

Answer (score 6):

> But when I prompt F2[1]*F[2], I get NA.

The second multiplicand refers to `F`, not to `F2`. This looks like a typo in your code and is probably where the NA is coming from.

Comment: Sharp eyes, now wait until the OP provides us with a reproducible example to get confirmation.